# Exposing R functionality as Web services method

Tags: r

I have a R script which does some statistical modelling. I would like to expose this script as web service method which I would consume from a mobile application. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried shiny? There are various approaches, which all boil down to running R from the server and fetching the results either directly with some form of integration or via files.

Comment: I would look at making it a CGI script.

Comment: My intension is to call the rscript from a mobile app using API, so felt webservices is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a standard Web Processing Service (WPS), also to consider if you intend to add different scripts/algorithms later, not only one. I would recommend you to have a look to the the [WPS4R](http://52north.org/communities/geoprocessing/wps/backends/52n-wps-r.html) backend. This page gives a tutorial that you can follow to expose quite easily R scripts as web-services.

For using your services in a web-page, you would then be able to configure easily a WPS client. They are several WPS javascript clients that are available on the web. For example, you can look to this [WPS client](https://github.com/Terradue/jquery-wps-client).